# Excel - How to Convert / Reverse the Column Sequence from Right to Left

Tags: excel

I have got an excel sheet with around 50 columns in it. But the current data is present in the opposite sequence of what is required.

Now how could I reverse the column sequence in such a way that the column at the very end on the right side, actually becomes the very first column on the left side and so on. I basically need to reverse the order of the columns.

I have already found a way to DISPLAY the data in that required format by using this method -
File, Options, Advanced,
Tick: Show Sheet Right to Left
Apply

But this just changes the DISPLAY and the not the Real Data within, so when I copy paste the data from this sheet, then it again shows the data in the original / wrong sequence only.

Please suggest how to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This small macro takes the columns on **Sheet1** and copies them to **Sheet2** in "flipped" order:

```
Sub ColumnFlipper()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim M As Long, N As Long, i As Long
    N = 1
    With s1
        M = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = M To 1 Step -1
            .Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy s2.Cells(1, N)
            N = N + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Modify the sheetnames to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

put this in A1 in another sheet, say **Sheet2**.

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R" & ROW()&"C" & X-COLUMN()+1;FALSE)
```

!!!**Sheet1** is the original sheet.
replace **X** with total number of columns. Fill right for **X** columns, then fill down.